# StreamSocket has no Close Implementation in C#

Tags: bluetooth, windows-runtime, proximity

Totally Weird.  There is a Close projection for C++ and JavaScript, and even .Net but not C# for WinRT.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.close.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1

I am successfully connecting using the very cool PeerFinder api.  When I want to force the connection to close, I dispose of the socket (as Close is not an option in C#).  This appears to work, but occasionally, subsequent connections connect to bluetooth, rather than WiFi.  Bluetooth is substantially slower than WiFi, so the experience is poor.
If I have Bluetooth turned off, then all works great, but I can't ask our customer to do that.

What is the correct way to Close a StreamSocket connection in C#?

Answer (score 2):

The docs you link say

> "For apps written using the .NET Framework 4.5 in C# and VB.NET, the
>   Close method is exposed as the Dispose() method on the StreamSocket."

The best way to use this method is via a using block

```
using(var stream = new StreamSocket())
{
}
```

The `Dispose` method will be called at the end of the block.

Comment: This is good for sample code, but for a large codebase, things are not as simple.  I am calling Dispose on the socket, and it appears to work fine (most of the time)